# Casting string to path expression - Schematron

Tags: string, casting, path, schematron

guys

I'm using schematron and I need to do the following:

Sometimes in the xml document I want to validate, there's elements like this:

```
<Var.X name="B">
```

For these elements (which name() has a dot in the middle) I need to see in the xml file if there's a diretory named Var with a child element with the attribute name = X (in this case), like this:

```
<Var>
   <Obj name="X">
</Var>
```

I thought of transforming the name() of those objects to a string representing the path, so for this case particularly:

Var.X would be /*/Var/child::*[@name="X"]

Having this string, then I wanted to check if there's, actually, an element belonging to the path the string represents, but I can't cast the string to path type, and I don't even know if that's possible...

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the name-function without an saxon-Extension!

```
<rule context="*[matches(name(),'\w\.\w')]">
    <let name="beforePoint" value="substring-before(name(),'.')"/>
    <let name="afterPoint" value="substring-after(name(),'.')"/>
    <assert test="/*/*[name() = $beforePoint]/*[@name=$afterPoint]">error message</assert>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that what I wanted to achieve is done with saxon:evaluate function... and I already achieved what I wanted